# Integral acceleration expression

Tags: integration

I have a small question! Where does the +20 and -40 come in the picture below. Here are the full expressions of the acceleration. a1=5*t,a2=-5*t+20, a3=5*t-40
In the picture there is max accelation of 10 and ares T1 = 2  and T2 = 6 and T=8
Teachers tip was to calculate with areas of the triangles, but i cant get the same answers.

[image: Picture of the acceleration]

**Please ask if you need more information and i will try to explain.**

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You are given the picture first and you are asked to try to figure out what equations represent the picture?  For that, to see the $+20$ or the $-40$, imagine that those lines extended all the way to the $y$-axis.  Where do they intersect with the $y$-axis?  Well, the line for $A2$ would intersect the $y$-axis at the point $(0,20)$.  That is where the $20$ comes from.

Comment: If instead, you are given the equations first... then the answer to the question of where the $20$ and the $-40$ come from would be "*from the author's imagination*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $+20$ comes from the fact that the function $a_2$ equals $10$ at $x=2$ and has a slope of $-5$. Putting this in the linear equation formula we get the $y$-intercept. Same thing for $a_3$

Comment: Okey. Just how exacly does it mean its +20 because it equals 10 at x = 2 ? and how does it translate to a3 ? when at x=6 its -10

Comment: @StudentFromFinland Let $a_2=-5x+b$, then we know that $10=-10+b$. Solve for $b$. Now let $a_3=5x+c$, we know that $-10=6*5+c=30+c$. Solve for $c$